# Ibeacon and Suggested apps

Tags: ios, ibeacon, lockscreen

I need to do that if is possible use the "Suggested apps" feature using IBeacons

This is my code:

self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid   major:1 minor:1 identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Background method's are called,like didRangeBeacons, but my lockscreen is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking! Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I have a iBeaconRegion registered in my locationManager. In the estimote's web, i found this: "All you need to do is set up regular beacon region monitoring (also known as a geofence) - and whenever your users enter the region being monitored by your app, its icon will automatically appear on the lock screen!"

My problem is that i have a regular beacon region registered, but i can't see the icon in the lock screen

Answer (score 3):

For the Suggested Apps feature, you need to use `startMonitoringForRegion` instead of the `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`.

Also, it seems you're doing ranging in the background (`[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` + a Background Mode for Location Services which I assume you enabled), you don't need that for the Suggested Apps feature. It'll drain the phone's battery (because it keeps the apps awake) and Apple usually rejects apps that do it without a good reason (e.g. a navigation app that's augmented with support for beacons).